# program function doesn't work. it can not pass variable

Tags: python

well, I want to make a program which checks the number of boxes.
but my python program doesn't work. I used python tutor, so, I knew that reason.
function(=def) can not pass variable. I do not know why this problem occurs...

```
a = 1

nsave = 100
vsave = 100
msave = 100
csave = 100

nsell = 0
vsell = 0
msell = 0
csell = 0

matrix = [[0]*3 for i in range(4)]
matrix[0][0] = "Nomal"
matrix[0][1] = nsave
matrix[0][2] = nsell
matrix[1][0] = "Vegetable"
matrix[1][1] = vsave
matrix[1][2] = vsell
matrix[2][0] = "Meat"
matrix[2][1] = msave
matrix[2][2] = msell
matrix[3][0] = "Cheese"
matrix[3][1] = csave
matrix[3][2] = csell


def choice(a):
    if (a == 1):
        nsave = nsave-1
        nsell = nsell+1
        if (matrix[0][1] < 0):
            print("error")
        else:
            for i in range(len(matrix)):
                for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                    print(matrix[i][j])
                    print()

    else:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: did you mean to `return` a value from your funtion? or what do you mean with 'functions can not pass a variable'?

Comment: i know, "def choice(a)" means choice function get value of 'a', in my brain, a is 1, so  some happen likes nsave-1, nsell+1 but any happen not occur...

Comment: so you want to call your function just like this `choice(a=1)`?

Comment: yes that' right!!!

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: umm.. if() dosen't work. i mean, in my knowlege, nsave and nsell will be change but it dosn't happen

Answer (score 1):

Here is your corrected code:

```
a = 1

nsave = 100
vsave = 100
msave = 100
csave = 100

nsell = 0
vsell = 0
msell = 0
csell = 0

matrix = [[0]*3 for i in range(4)]
matrix[0][0] = "Nomal"
matrix[0][1] = nsave
matrix[0][2] = nsell
matrix[1][0] = "Vegetable"
matrix[1][1] = vsave
matrix[1][2] = vsell
matrix[2][0] = "Meat"
matrix[2][1] = msave
matrix[2][2] = msell
matrix[3][0] = "Cheese"
matrix[3][1] = csave
matrix[3][2] = csell


def choice(a):
    global nsave
    global nsell

    if (a == 1):
        nsave = nsave-1
        nsell = nsell+1
        if (matrix[0][1] < 0):
            print("error")
        else:
            for i in range(len(matrix)):
                for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                    print(matrix[i][j])
                    print()

    else:
        print("Error")

choice(a)
```